# Неверная кодировка возвращает знаки "??????"

Tags: кодировка, php, mysql

Кодировка сервера, кодировка БД, кодировка Таблиц, и файлов: `UTF-8`. В итоге русские буквы, которые я вытягиваю заменяются "знаками вопросами".

```
    mysql_client_encoding() вернул Latin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не будет лишним поставить при соединении кодировку.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "bd");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

Так же перевести файлы (весь проект) в utf-8 и ставить заголовок charset=UTF-8 в html

Answer (score -1):

Значит страница в `win-1251` кодировке.

Вариантов то немного.